How to dissolve Copper sulphate in oils
We need to mix copper sulphate in certain oils to prepare an antiseptic oil. For that we need to dissolve copper sulphate in oils. How to do that?

A man put an electric kettle on a gas stove. The kettle melts. The man goes to the dedicated forum and asks how to put an electric kettle on a gas stove. Same thing here. Maybe you don't need copper sulphate in oil at all.

What a user asks about may confuse and hide what the user wants to do and what the user needs to know to achieve his goal.  A broader context, background, purpose and relevant details could help in the delivering the optimal answer for the goal, instead of for the question.

Disclaimer: Be aware that medical-related questions asked at Chemistry SE site are explicitly off topic.
You cannot dissolve copper sulfate in oil.
The best you can do is making suspension of finely milled particles, but that is not probably applicable. Copper sulfate is highly polar substance and cupric ions are highly polarizing ions. You would have better luck with dissolving (that is not emulgation) of water in oil than copper sulfate.
What you could do is making an emulsion "water in oil" where the water based phase would contain dissolved copper sulfate.
Otherwise, you need some lipophilic (soluble in fats/oil) antiseptic agens.
BTW oil is too vague category, putting in a single box many very different compounds or mixtures with very different chemical properties, sharing just hydrophobicity and rheological parameters.
